# UIActivityItemProvider's -item method: waiting for an NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've got a `UIActivityItemProvider` subclass which is supposed to provide an `NSURL` to the `UIActivityViewController` by doing the following:

- Upload an image to my server
- Receive a URL from the server
- Provide that URL to the sharers.

It seemed fairly straightforward in theory: set up the `placeholderItem` method to return a dummy NSURL, and then set up all the logic to handle the uploading etc. in the `item` method.

The problem is that the `item` method is a single, synchronous method which is called on a background thread and is supposed to handle all the processing and return an item (in this case, an `NSURL`)... and the methods I need to use to handle uploading are asynchronous (namely, I create an `NSURLConnection` with  the `UIActivityItemProvider` subclass as its delegate, respond to its delegate methods to update my UI with a progress indicator, and so on... but I can't just do that within the `item` method because I can't let `item` return until it has its URL.

My attempt at a solution was to have the `item` method trigger the URL Connection and then jump into this loop:

```
    while ((self.uploadedFileURL == nil) && (self.uploadErrorMessage == nil)) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
        NSLog(@"Waiting for upload...");
    }
```

and then I rely on the various `NSURLConnection` delegate methods to update progress etc.  In the `didFinishLoading` and `didFailWithError` delegate methods, I give values to `self.uploadedFileURL` and `self.uploadErrorMessage`, respectively.

But: This doesn't work.  The `NSURLConnection` never fires a delegate method, and I have to assume it's blocked for some reason.  I get a "Waiting for upload..." in the log every second as I'd expect to, but nothing else happens.

What am I missing here?

**update:** I have found a solution of sorts, but it's less than ideal: using a synchronous request in the `-item` method. Big downside is that I can't show a progress indicator, and there's no good handling of network errors.  So... Still looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I discovered a quite good solution. The following gist provides a pseudo-synchronous variant of the NSURLConnection methods:

https://gist.github.com/SQiShER/5009086

"Pseudo-synchronous" in that the methods it provides return their values synchronously, but are using the async methods in the back end. I'm sure that's not really a legitimate term, but it's all I've got :)

Anyway, the code at the link responds to some but not all of the nsurlconnection delegate methods... It's trivial to add more, though.  If someone sees this and wants some more detail, comment and I'll take the time to flesh out this answer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the same?

Comment: @Suran This is far from fresh in my memory since it was a couple of years ago; Best advice would be to look at the gist I linked to. The code provides synchronous methods that wait in a loop until the asynchronous request is completed, and then return. In other words, to the caller, these methods appear completely synchronous, even though they are actually calling async methods to perform their duties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Finally I ended up using similar approach only. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a subclass of `UIActivity` instead. Override `-[UIActivity performActivity]` and start your download there. Once you're done use

```
[self activityDidFinish:YES];
```

to continue.

Comment: The problem is that I need this behavior to apply to other apps' Share Extensions in ios8, which to the best of my understanding behave just like UIActivities except there's no way to subclass them (since I have no access to the class)... I have another active question here asking if there's a way to supplant certain sharers with my own variants (or possibly other mechanisms).  But if I am going to make *this* solution work, whatever I'm doing has to be done with no access to the UIActivity itself.

Comment: I understand. I completely missed the point of your question.